# C: Valgrind: Use of uninitialized value of size 4 AND Use of uninitialised value of size 4

Tags: c, valgrind

These 2 errors are coming up with a linked list/low level file read/strtok program.

```
==10982== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==10982==    at 0x40C3899: strtok (strtok.S:197)
==10982==    by 0x8048719: main (main.c:9)
==10982==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10982==    at 0x80487D2: buildList (functions.c:13)
==10982== 
==10982== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==10982==    at 0x40C38C1: strtok (strtok.S:223)
==10982==    by 0x8048719: main (main.c:9)
==10982==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10982==    at 0x80487D2: buildList (functions.c:13)
==10982== 
==10982== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10982==    at 0x40C38C4: strtok (strtok.S:224)
==10982==    by 0x8048719: main (main.c:9)
==10982==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10982==    at 0x80487D2: buildList (functions.c:13)
```

Here is the function buildList

```
void buildList(int fdin, int lines)
{
    char ara[4096];
    int num;
    double p;
    read(fdin, ara, 4096);
    char *nl = "\n";
    char *ws = " ";
    char *temp =  strtok(ara, " ");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        Stock *s = (Stock*)calloc(1, sizeof(Stock));
        s->c.symbol = (char*)calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(s->c.symbol, temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        s->c.name = (char*)calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(s->c.name, temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        sscanf(temp, "%lf", &p);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        s->price = p;
        sscanf(temp, "%d", &num);
        s->shares = num;
        Node *n = (Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
        n->data = s;
        addOrdered(n);
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    close(fdin);
}
```

I cannot figure out why this error occurs. From what I've read it is because I am assigning things to a char* from strtok without assigning any memory to them. However this is how I have done it in the past and I think it has been fine.

Comment: Which is line 13 of functions.c?

Comment: Looks like Valgrind is missing the fact that `ara` is being "initialized" by `read()`. Just for grins, try putting something like `memset(ara, 0, sizeof(ara))` right before the read, and see if that supresses the warning. If it does, then remove it and know that you can safely ignore the warning (or find out how to get Valgrind to shut up). Of course, `read()` might also be failing, in which case Valgrind is correct.

Comment: You don't provide the definition of `main`, nor do you show the input that's causing the problem.  Nor do you do any error checking anywhere in the above code.  Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that doesn't require us to guess!

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker 
Ya, that memset solved all 3 errors. Thanks! I'll look into memset to see what it does.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker
if you post as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6):

As others have surmised, `valgrind` is complaining that `strtok` is making use of uninitialized memory. The question then turns to why, since it seems like it is being initialized by:

```
read(fdin, ara, 4096);
```

However, `read()` does not `\0` terminate the data, while `strtok` expects a `\0` terminated string. Make sure the input is terminated properly:

```
ssize_t result = read(fdin, ara, sizeof(ara)-1); /* leave room for '\0' */
ara[result > 0 ? result : 0] = '\0';
```

---

The `memset(ara, 0, sizeof(ara));` suggestion by Lee Daniel Crocker amounts to the same kind of fix, but it only works if the file contains less than `sizeof(ara)` bytes of input. You are still exposed to a similar problem if the file you read from has 4096 bytes of data or more. Then, `strtok` will be forced to scan past the end of the buffer to look for the `\0`, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: But the call to `strtok` that it's complaining about is in `main`, not in the above function...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I think that is just because the function got inlined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't use strtok anywhere in main.

Answer (score 3):

> `read(fdin, ara, 4096);`

...which could return:

- -1, meaning the read got an error, and `ara` wasn't filled in;
- 0, meaning you hit the end of the file, and `ara` wasn't filled in;
- a value < 4096, meaning there are fewer than 4096 bytes left in the file, and not all of the bytes of `ara` are filled in.

Always check the return value of `read()`.

> char *temp =  strtok(ara, " ");

```
$ man strtok
```

...

```
The strtok() function is used to isolate sequential tokens in a null-ter-
minated string, str. ...
```

There is nothing whatsoever that guarantees that `ara` has a null character (`'\0'`) in it, so you cannot validly hand it to `strtok()`.  Make it `char ara[4097]` and do `ara[4096] = '\0';` after the read if you want to make sure that there's a `'\0'` in it.

Or, even better, if `read()`'s return value is in a variable `data_read`, and you've already checked to make sure it's not -1, do `ara[data_read] = '\0';`, so that you set the byte after the last one read to `'\0'`.

And what happens if the file has more than 4096 characters, and your `read()` call reads in, for example, several lines and the *beginning* of another line?  Given that, you might want to consider using `fopen()` to open the file and use `fgets()` to read lines.

Answer (score 1):

Does the data read by `read` have a null terminator at the end? If not, that's probably the issue.